# Can I suppress .local for stackalloc in C# without using unsafe?

Tags: c#, unsafe, stackalloc

To allocate a `double` array initialized to zero, you can choose

`var x = new double[N];`

to allocate on the heap and

`Span<double> x = stackalloc double[N];`

to allocate on the stack.

To suppress initialization to zero, you can call

`var x = GC.AllocateUninitializedArray<double>(N);`

to allocate on the heap, but I don't know how to do the same thing on the stack. You can use the `SkipLocalsInit` property, but that then requires compiling in unsafe. Is there a way to achieve this result but not use unsafe?

Comment: No, use Help > Send Feedback > Suggest a feature to make your case.

Comment: It's inherently unsafe so how would you want to do this without using `unsafe`?

Comment: @Charlieface It's unsafe if you initialize it to a pointer, but not if you initialize it to a `Span`.

Comment: I didn't mean you need `unsafe` context to read the data. It's unsafe in the sense you are reading uninitialized memory, which is why `SkipLocalsInit` needs compiling in `unsafe` mode. Memory is not supposed to be readable after the location has been dropped/cleared by GC, you end up reading someone else's data.

Comment: @Charlieface So, are you implying the fact that `GC.AllocateUninitializedArray<double>(N)` can be run without `unsafe` is inappropriate or a security bug?

Comment: Kind of, there are now quite a few framework functions which do `unsafe` things without needing `unsafe`. See for example the whole `Unsafe` class. You just need to be aware that it's somewhat breaking the contract of the way memory is supposed to work in .NET. `stackalloc` originally started off as a completely `unsafe` feature, and it was only with `Span<T>` that it become not so.